# How to pad a binary string with zeros?

Tags: c#, string, formatting, binary, format

```
string binary = Convert.ToString(15, 2);

Console.WriteLine("{0}", binary);
```

Prints:

`1111`

I want it to print `00001000`

Because the data type is of string and not integer I cannot do something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:00000000}", binary);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine( binary.PadLeft(8, '0'));
```

Answer (score 11):

You can try this one:

`Convert.ToString(15, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');`

It should give you `00001111`