# Converting from hex to binary without losing leading 0's using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hex

I want to convert a hexadecimal to its equivalent binary. The code I have tried is as below:

```
string hex_addr = "0001A000";
string bin_value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(hex_addr, 16), 2);
```

This will truncate the leading zeros. How do I achieve this?

Comment: As far as I can tell this code actually works fine when

   string hex_addr = "0001A000";

It outputs, "11010000000000000".  It doesn't make any difference whether the hex value has leading 0s or not.

Answer (score 3):

Try following (from the [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6617626/649524))

```
private static readonly Dictionary<char, string> hexCharacterToBinary = new Dictionary<char, string> {
    { '0', "0000" },
    { '1', "0001" },
    { '2', "0010" },
    { '3', "0011" },
    { '4', "0100" },
    { '5', "0101" },
    { '6', "0110" },
    { '7', "0111" },
    { '8', "1000" },
    { '9', "1001" },
    { 'a', "1010" },
    { 'b', "1011" },
    { 'c', "1100" },
    { 'd', "1101" },
    { 'e', "1110" },
    { 'f', "1111" }
};

public string HexStringToBinary(string hex) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in hex) {
        // This will crash for non-hex characters. You might want to handle that differently.
        result.Append(hexCharacterToBinary[char.ToLower(c)]);
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I had used this in one of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Just use PadLeft( , ):

```
string strTemp = System.Convert.ToString(buf, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
```

Here buf is your string hex_addr, strTemp is the result. 8 is the length which you can change to your desired length of binary string.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to PadLeft as suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682628/how-to-pad-a-binary-string-with-zeros)

```
bin_value.PadLeft(32, '0')
```