# Convert decimal to binary but in an 8 bit format

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pad a binary string with zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682628/how-to-pad-a-binary-string-with-zeros)

I am able to convert decimal numbers to binary but not in an 8 bit format. For example if I input `5` the result is `101` which is correct but how can I show the result in an 8 bit format such as `00000101`?

```
string result = Convert.ToString(num, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
```

Comment: Despite the edit, the question remains an exact duplicate. I see no reason to reopen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use

```
string result = Convert.ToString(num, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
```

Comment: +1. Excellent (and succinct) answer.